# Countdown Timer NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a timer in Unity but always got error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour{

public int timeLeft = 5;
public Text countdownText;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("LoseTime");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    countdownText.text = ("Time Left = " + timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft <= 0)
    {
        StopCoroutine("LoseTime");
        countdownText.text = "Times Up!";
    }
}

IEnumerator LoseTime()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        timeLeft--;
    }
}
}
```

please Help

Comment: My error is at   countdownText.text = ("Time Left = " + timeLeft);

Comment: You are not initializing `countdownText` in your code. Also, Avoid using public fields. Use public properties instead.

Comment: You should initialize `public int timeLeft = 5;` locally inside `Update()` function

Comment: `countdownText = new Text()`....

Comment: already tried, still cannot resolve

Comment: When I Compile it it does not show error, but when I run It will show the error

Comment: you need to assign it onw of your exisiting text component in Awake or Start method. something like  `countdownText = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();` . With correct type, or give it a tag and search by tag.